# LinkedIn Posts API returns INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: linkedin-api

Running into an issue when trying to call the Posts API.

I'm getting a list of the authenticated user's posts through `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author=AUTHOR_URN` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-07&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors) which worked yesterday but not anymore today.

I am convinced I changed something between then and now, but whatever I do I cannot seem to get the request to work anymore.
The error returned does not give me a lot of information either:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500,
    "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
}
```

I also created a request to fetch images yesterday, which does still work:
`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/ids=List(IMAGE_URN)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/images-api?view=li-lms-2022-07&tabs=http#batch-get-images)

URN I'm using for the `/posts` request is formatted as follows: `urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<REDACTED>` (where `<REDACTED>` is the numeric author identifier).

Confirmed the headers are the same between the `/posts` request and `/images` request.

Headers for reference:

```
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_REDACTED
X-Restli-Protocol-version: 2.0.0
LinkedIn-Version: 202207
```

Is there anything I'm missing here that I need to get my `/posts` request working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have same problem. It seems like a bug. When you try previous V2 version of API call, service returns posts correctly (without error). Hope, that LinkedIn handle it and improve documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to someone from LinkedIn support since the issue occurred for me. Their response:

> It's possible that you were getting that error due to a small hiccup on our side at that time - This can happen when we deploy updates or fixes.

Since then I've not seen this happen anymore, so expecting this is the case. Closing as answered.